# how to get user's location using google api

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse{
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

            mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {


            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)


            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }


}
```

This is the code I have written, but I am not able get the user's location. 
I have added `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescriptation` in `info.plist` .
Can somebody help me on this? I have been trying this from a long time.

I am getting error in these lines.

```
=================================
mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

==================================
```

Can somebody help me to fix this?

1 Value of type 'MKMapView' has no member 'myLocationEnabled'
2 Value of type 'MKMapView' has no member ‘settings'
3 Cannot assign value of type 'GMSCameraPosition!' to type 'MKMapCamera'

this are the 3 error am getting

my exact error is on @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
is i change this @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
i get thread 1 error @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView! in this only map show but doesn't pin my location

and am not add comment for the answer

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the error that you are receiving?

Comment: As I remember, you don't need to add something in info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring an instance of `MKMapView` (the mapView provided by the MapKit Framework). You should use an instance of `GMSMapView`, the map of the Google Maps Framework, in order to use these functions.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve done it that way and it works like a charm:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var mapView:GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if(error != nil) {

            print("Error:" + error!.localizedDescription )
            return

        }

        if(placemarks!.count > 0) {

            if let pm = placemarks?.first {
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            }

        } else {
            print("Error with data")
        }

    });

}

func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark) {
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Error with Server");
}
```

Comment: You already have an variable with the name "mapView" - have you included the pod for GoogleMaps?

Comment: You should be careful when you try to combine things from MKMapView (Apple) and GMSMapView (Google)

Comment: i have add @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

Comment: And you have GoogleMaps for iOS included to your project? Do you see any map?

Comment: So you have included GoogleMaps to your project and you are able to compile (after cleaning maybe) - but then receive an Error - where? Which line of code? Any details?